# Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0]

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a source code of an app, and it shows the error below.

```
 Build file 'C:\Users\SQ\Downloads\application\build.gradle' line: 24

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'application'.
> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

In settings > gradle it shows an error in gradle-wrapper.properties, I tried changing it to specific location but the error changed.

Error:

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 
'application'.
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
...... 177 more
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please do not change  location of build.gradle. Replace it on its origin destination. And Upload your build.gradle.

Comment: @Younus How to do that please?

Comment: What? @Ali Liftawe